# Hive Sort Merge Bucket Map(SMB Map) Join

Tags: join, hive, smb

I ran the query with and without SMB join and got different results. Please help explain.

```
SET hive.enforce.bucketing=true;

create table dbaproceduresbuckets (
owner           string ,
object_name     string ,
procedure_name  string ,
object_id       double ,
subprogram_id   double ,
overload        string ,
object_type     string ,
aggregate       string ,
pipelined       string ,
impltypeowner   string ,
impltypename    string ,
parallel        string ,
interface       string ,
deterministic   string ,
authid          string )
CLUSTERED BY (object_id) SORTED BY (OBJECT_ID ASC) INTO 32 BUCKETS;

CREATE TABLE dbaobjectsbuckets1(
owner            string,
object_name      string,
subobject_name   string,
object_id        double,
data_object_id   double,
object_type      string,
created          string,
last_ddl_time    string,
timestamp        string,
status           string,
temporary        string,
generated        string,
secondary        string,
namespace        double,
edition_name     string) CLUSTERED BY (object_id) SORTED BY (OBJECT_ID ASC) INTO 32 BUCKETS;

**** load the table;
```

0: jdbc:hive2://xxxxxx:10000> select count(*) from dbaobjectsbuckets1 a, dbaproceduresbuckets b
0: jdbc:hive2://xxxxxxxx:10000> where a.object_id = b.object_id;
INFO  : Hadoop job information for Stage-2: number of mappers: 3; number of reducers: 1
INFO  : 2016-06-13 15:56:00,381 Stage-2 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
INFO  : 2016-06-13 15:56:55,818 Stage-2 map = 1%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 122.6 sec
INFO  : 2016-06-13 15:57:47,124 Stage-2 map = 7%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 326.86 sec
..........
INFO  : 2016-06-13 16:05:01,246 Stage-2 map = 100%,  reduce = 100%, Cumulative CPU 867.1 sec
INFO  : MapReduce Total cumulative CPU time: 14 minutes 27 seconds 100 msec
INFO  : Ended Job = job_1464280256859_0146
+--------+--+
|  _c0   |
+--------+--+
| 54876  |
+--------+--+

```
**** 
set hive.auto.convert.sortmerge.join=true; 
set hive.optimize.bucketmapjoin=true;
set hive.optimize.bucketmapjoin.sortedmerge=true;
set hive.auto.convert.sortmerge.join.noconditionaltask=true;
set hive.enforce.bucketing=true;
set hive.enforce.sorting=true;   

0: jdbc:hive2://xxxxxxx:10000> select count(*) from   dbaobjectsbuckets1 a, dbaproceduresbuckets b
```

0: jdbc:hive2://xxxxxxxx:10000> where a.object_id = b.object_id;

```
in the execution plan, I am seeing
```

|               Sorted Merge Bucket Map Join Operator                                                      |
|                 condition map:                                                                           |
|                      Inner Join 0 to 1                                                                   |
|                 keys:                                                                                    |
|                   0 object_id (type: double)                                                             |
|                   1 object_id (type: double)

```
 **** but the result is showing
 INFO  : Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of mappers: 32; number of reducers: 1
  ......
 INFO  : MapReduce Total cumulative CPU time: 4 minutes 8 seconds 490 msec
```

INFO  : Ended Job = job_1464280256859_0150
+------+--+
| _c0  |
+------+--+
| 2    |
+------+--+

????? My question is why it only got 2 when I used SMB join?????? It is supposed to be 54876.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

use sort by clause while inserting data into sorted table

or

```
set hive.enforce.sorting=true
```

before inserting data into sorted table